# AutoScraper module not found in Python Autoscraper library

Tags: python, web-scraping, import, pycharm, package

I wanted to try autoscraper library for python
https://github.com/alirezamika/autoscraper
I open new project in Pycharm with vir env Python 3.8 and installed autoscraper library. Together with it, more packages were added (like bs4 etc.). When I try to import AutoScraper object

```py
from autoscraper import AutoScraper
```

PyCharm is not finding the module.
When I open the module script in `./lib/python3.8/site-packages/autoscraper/auto_scraper.py` it shows the problem is in import from the second file in the package utils.py

I made screenshots of my steps. Can you please advise what I am doing wrong and how to get the package working?

Creating the vir env:

[image: Creating the vir env]

Importing autoscraper library:

[image: Importing autoscraper library]

Import - module AutoScraper not found

[image: Import - module AutoScraper not found]

error in auto_scraper.py file
[image: error in auto_scraper.py file]

utils.py file
[image: utils.py file]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in naming the file in the same way like module --> autoscraper and autoscraper. When I renamed the project and file to new_scraping_project & new_scraping_project.py it worked well.